# How to index over specific column in list of arrays?

Tags: python, list

I have

```
list1 = [[50,0.43],[45,0.66]]
```

And I want to get all the second elements in each array so I would like:

```
[0.43,0.66]
```

Also, if I want to check if 50 is in list1, how do I do that? Because using

```
50 in list1
```

returns `False`.

Comment: If you do a lot of this, you will really want to use numpy instead

Comment: `any(50 in i for i in list1)` for your second issue, `[i[1] for i in list1]` for your first

Comment: Please don't ask two different questions in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1.**

```
for i in list1[1]:
    print(i)
```

**2.**

```
50 in list1[0]
```

Remember there are 2 list in list1. Which means they are list of list.

Comment: Neither of these do what the OP wants

Comment: I answered his question.

Comment: no. The first one prints the first row, and the second one returns if 50  is in the first row

Comment: No no I think that you were getting wrong and also he may be in baby step in programming.